# How do I emulate the behavior of @android:id/empty in an Activity that is not a ListActivity?

Tags: android

According to the [`ListActivity` documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html), when `@android:id/empty` is defined, it will show a message instead of a `ListView` indicating that there is no data in the list. My Activity subclasses a custom Activity that I wrote, so it cannot simply subclass a ListActivity on its own.

I have attempted to do this in xml to try to emulate this behavior. Here is my current layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/titleReviewData"
        android:gravity="center" android:textSize="24sp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp" />

    <ListView android:id="@+id/reviewList"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2" />

    <TextView android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="No data" />

    <Button android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:text="@string/textReviseButton"
        android:onClick="revise" />
    <Button android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:text="@string/textSubmitButton"
        android:onClick="submit" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The layout is supposed to show a `TextView` title, the `ListView` or empty message under it, and two buttons stuck to the bottom of the layout. Unfortunately, the addition of the empty message is not rendered properly.

The only code I have in the corresponding Activity at the moment is code that sets an adapter for `@id/reviewList` and lots of code to open dialog boxes. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your activity code you can set any view to act as the empty view by using [listview.setEmptyView(emptyView)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setEmptyView%28android.view.View%29). It does not need to have the specific id: **@android:id/empty**. You can either declare the empty view in your XML document or create it in Java. After you have the view call setEmptyView(emptyView)